# how to redirect to a link with $number

Tags: php, redirect, header

I want to redirect the visitor as following

```
<?php

$page2_id = 2;          
header("Location:./index.php?page=$page2_id");

?>
```

The page on the address bar is correct, but the page doesn't appear and i got this error

> Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for
>   this address in a way that will never complete.

also the following redirection doesn't work !!

```
<?php

header("Location:./index.php?page=26");

?>
```

can any one help me?

Comment: try to remove dot `header("Location:/index.php?page=$page2_id");
`

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove dot after `Location:`

```
$page2_id = 2; 
header("Location:/index.php?page=$page2_id");
```